# #1072 - Key column 'COUNTRY' doesn't exist in table

Tags: mysql

These are my parent tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LANGUAGE_SPOKE(

LanguageCode CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY,

LanguageName VARCHAR(50)

) ENGINE = INNODB; 


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS COUNTRY(

CountryCode CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY,

CountryName VARCHAR(50)

) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

This is child table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS COUNTRY_LANGUAGE(

LanguageCode CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY,

CountryCode CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY,

FOREIGN KEY (COUNTRY) REFERENCES CountryCode(COUNTRY),

FOREIGN KEY (LANGUAGE_SPOKE) REFERENCES LanguageCode(LANGUAGE_SPOKE)

) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

this post apparently doesn't have enough detail so here are words to let me edit this for some reason

Comment: can you describe more detailed what are you doing and what is the exact error message you get? I can't see `userid` on your scripts.

Comment: Shortly: yes, this error message is correct.

Comment: The error may be coming from a trigger(s)/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got these wrong:

```
FOREIGN KEY (COUNTRY) REFERENCES CountryCode(COUNTRY),
FOREIGN KEY (LANGUAGE_SPOKE) REFERENCES LanguageCode(LANGUAGE_SPOKE)
```

After `REFERENCES` it should be `table_name(column_name)`. You got it the other way round.